# How can I get e.g. "en_US" from Locale.getISOCountries();

Tags: java, locale, iso, country

how can get for e.g. "en_US" from `Locale.getISOCountries()`; 
=> Not from `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`
Because with `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`I got not all Iso3 County Codes. There some with NULL.

I try

```
for (String countryCode : locales) {
    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
    obj.toString()
```

But I got only e.g. **_US**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're creating a new, custom `Locale`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: yes, I want to get the Locale ID from each country and the Country Id (Iso)

Locale ID = en_US Country Id = US

But I can´t find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work. You have to specify the language in Locale(language, country) if you want en_US. For US, there are two official languages, spanish and english. So, two results will come for the below code

```
Locale[] localeArray = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

for (Locale countryLocale : localeArray) {
Locale obj = new Locale(countryLocale.getLanguage(), countryLocale.getCountry());
obj.toString();

if (countryLocale.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("US"))
System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```